# Refactoring a modelica library that doesn't use flow variable and stream variables

Tags: refactoring, fluid, modelica, dymola

I am digging into a modelica library called ThermoSysPro, but the connectors in this library don't use any flow variable and stream variable. This affects the code in the other components.

So If I wanna refactoring the code in this library, could anyone show me a similar example? Especially how to rewrite the code in the components to use stream variables.

[image]

Comment: The starting point for finding libraries with similar components would probably be here: https://modelica.org/libraries

Comment: Same page, without the frame: https://impact.modelica.org/libraries.html

Comment: Actually, I want to find a example of comparison between using flow variables, stream variables and not using them with the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such example available. Nevertheless quite some work has been carried out in that regard. As a starting point I would suggest to read [this](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/043/012/ecp09430078.pdf). It explains in detail, which concepts have been used and why they have been sub-optimal. This includes in-/output, flow and stream connectors, also covering the Modelica-related fundamentals of each approach. It should therefore pretty much answer your question.